# Node.js + Socket.io: When trying to use socket-anti-spam module, EADDRINUSE error appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use the `socket-anti-spam` module (https://github.com/michaeldegroot/socket-anti-spam) in my web application. However, when I try using it, I get the following error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

Below is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");
var socketListen = socket.listen(3000);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var SocketAntiSpam = require("socket-anti-spam");

require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variable.env' });

// Initialize Node.JS application
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static("public", {
    dotfiles: 'allow'
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const socketAntiSpam = new SocketAntiSpam({
    banTime:            30,         // Ban time in minutes
    kickThreshold:      2,          // User gets kicked after this many spam score
    kickTimesBeforeBan: 1,          // User gets banned after this many kicks
    banning:            true,       // Uses temp IP banning after kickTimesBeforeBan
    io:                 socketListen,  // Bind the socket.io variable
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to listen on the same port (3000) twice that’s why you are getting “Address In Use” error.

Try something like:

```
const SocketAntiSpam  = require('socket-anti-spam')
const app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const listen = server.listen(3000);

const socketAntiSpam = new SocketAntiSpam({
  banTime:            30,
  kickThreshold:      2,
  kickTimesBeforeBan: 1,
  banning:            true,
  io:                 io,
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('spam', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
});

app.get('/hello', (request, response) => {
  response.send('ok');
});
```

Comment: I need to use the socket-anti-spam module in my code. This answer does not include the socket-anti-spam module.